# What is a correct preposition after "clusterize"?

Tags: prepositions

What is a correct preposition after "clusterize"? The sentence context is:

> We have clusterize data in/into/on/... several groups

Comment: *Clusterize* is not a very common word, so it's difficult to say.  Is this a sentence you found somewhere, or is it one that you're writing?  Is there a reason you want to say *clusterize* and not just *cluster*?

Answer (score 2):

> We have *to* **cluster** data **into** several groups.

*into* is often used when the composition of things changes. See [*into*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/into):

> 9. *preposition*
>      If something changes **into** something else, it then has a new form, shape, or nature.

Regarding *clusterize*, see [*cluster*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cluster).